# Unable to install ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, installation, errors

I'm trying to install ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04, for that I use this [doc](https://docs.ros.org/en/dashing/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html). I noticed some errors on this doc like in the "Installing and initializing rosdep" part, instead of

`sudo apt install -y python-rosdep`

I had to do

`sudo apt install -y python3-rosdep2`

and in the "Installing the missing dependencies" part, instead of

```
rosdep install --from-paths ~/ros2_dashing/ros2-linux/share --ignore-src --rosdistro dashing -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 osrf_testing_tools_cpp poco_vendor rmw_connext_cpp rosidl_typesupport_connext_c rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 tinyxml_vendor tinyxml2_vendor urdfdom urdfdom_headers"
```

I did

```
rosdep install --from-paths ~/Documents/ros2_dashing/ros2-linux/share --ignore-src --rosdistro dashing -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 osrf_testing_tools_cpp poco_vendor rmw_connext_cpp rosidl_typesupport_connext_c rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 tinyxml_vendor tinyxml2_vendor urdfdom urdfdom_headers iceoryx_binding_c cyclonedds"
```

(To help you, I added 'iceoryx_binding_c cyclonedds')

Now I'm at this step:

`./setup.sh` in the "Environment setup / Sourcing the setup script" part but I have this error:

`The build time path "/home/jenkins-agent/workspace/packaging_linux/ws/install" doesn't exist. Either source a script for a different shell or set the environment variable "COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX" explicitly.`

And I have no clue of what to do to fix this error. Did I do something wrong ?

And a last thing but I think it's not related (I hope), but my `ros2_bashing` folder is not at the path `~/ros2_bashing` like in documentation but at `~/Documents/ros2_bashing`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to install ROS2 Dashing which is already EOL and worked on Ubuntu 18.04. For Ubuntu 22.04 you should install ROS 2 Humble following this steps [Installing ROS2 Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/index.html)